# Laravel Relationships saving an array

Tags: laravel, schema

I'm working on my first ever laravel project a crm. In my crm you can create appointments and packages. Now for the appointments I need to be able to select packages and set a relationship however I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly.

In my appointments model I have this in a function `return $this->hasMany('App\Package');`

and in my package model I have this in a function `return $this->belongsTo('App\Appointment');`

I'm having difficulty in understanding is when I'm creating a new appointment and I select a package how do I save that packages data(array) to the DB so that if I want a collection of appointments I can see what package was assigned to that appointment?

Should I be able to see the relationship from the DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent provides convenient methods for adding new models to relationships.

you may use the [associate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model:

```
//...
$appointment = new App\Appointment(['column' => 'value']);

$package = App\Package::find(1);

$appointment->packages()->associate($package);

$appointment->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it it looks like you have one-to-one relationship between Appointment and Package.

You can attach Package to Appointment using `associate` method on the relationship.

```
$appointment = Appointment::find(1);
$package = Package::find(1);

$appointment->package()->associate($package);
```

[Belongs To Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Save Array Data in Relationship

```php
$appointment->package()->createMany($packages);
```